# Integration on measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Hey guys thank you for helping me, It's vanishing property and finiteness property. and I wanna prove:
$f\ge0$ and $f$ is measurable. Then,
1.  $\int fd\lambda=0 \Longleftrightarrow \{x|f(x)>0\}$ is a null set. 
2.  $\int fd\lambda<\infty \Longrightarrow \{x|f(x)=\infty\}$ is a null set. 
I don't know how can I approach. please help me. thx

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

1. If $\{x\mid f(x)>0\}$ is a null set, then $f=0$ almost everywhere and so its integral is $0$. Conversely, assume that $\int fd\lambda=0$. Then writing 
   $$\{x\mid f(x)>0\}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\{x\mid f(x)\geq \frac 1n\}$$ and noticing that 
   $$\lambda\{x\mid f(x)\geq \frac 1n\}\leq n\int fd\lambda=0,$$ 
   we have written $\{x\mid f(x)> 0\}$ as a countable union of sets of measure $0$, so this set has measure $0$ (an is measurable).
2. We can write $\{x\mid f(x)=+\infty\}=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\{x\mid f(x)\geq n\}$. Since 
   $$\mu\{x\mid f(x)\geq n\}\leq \frac 1n\int fd\lambda,$$
   we have, because all the involved sets have finite measure 
   $$\mu\{x\mid f(x)=+\infty\}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu\{x\mid f(x)\geq n\}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. <br>
But I'm not sure why these two note:
$$\lambda\{x\mid f(x)\geq \frac 1n\}\leq n\int fd\lambda=0,$$ $$\lambda\{x\mid f(x)\geq n\}\leq \frac 1n\int fd\lambda,$$

Comment: If $A$ is a real number, $A\lambda(x\mid f(x)\geq A)\leq \int f(x) \lambda$.

Comment: Just wondering: why is the converse of 2 not necessarily true? Thank you.

Comment: Take $f(x)=\frac 1x$ on $(0,1)$.